# requiring an object literal with functions

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I'm trying to clean up some code I found in a hapi server `index.js`..

There's some code that sets up Apple's Push Network , then attaches itself via a variable on the `server.apnConnection`

my problem is when i try to call functions that I had setup .. they are missing / not there.

**index.js**

```
server = require('./config/server/hapi.js')(config, process.env.NODE_URL);
server.apnConnection = require('./config/server/applepush.js');
server.apnConnection.note("test");
```

**applepush.js**

```
'use strict';

var apn = require('apn');
var Path = require('path');

module.exports = function() {

    var options = {
        gateway: 'www.mapple.com',
        errorCallback: function(errorNum, notification){
            console.log('Error is: %s', errorNum);
            console.log('Note ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
        },
        cert: process.env.APPLE_CERT || Path.join(config.rootPath, '../cert.pem'),
        key:  process.env.APPLE_KEY || Path.join(config.rootPath, '../key.pem'),
        enhanced: true,
        production: false,
        cacheLength: 100,
        port: 2195
    };
    var apnConn = new apn.Connection(options);
    apnConn.on('connected',function(){
        console.log('connected to apn');
    });
    apnConn.on('transmitted', function(notification, device) {
        console.log('Notification transmitted to:' + device.token.toString('hex'));
    });
    apnConn.on('transmissionError', function(errCode, notification, device) {
        console.error('Notification caused error: ' + errCode + ' for device ', device, notification);
        if (errCode === 8) {
            console.log('A error code of 8 indicates that the device token is invalid. This could be for a number of reasons - are you using the correct environment? i.e. Production vs. Sandbox');
        }
    });
    apnConn.on('timeout', function () {
        console.log('APNS Connection Timeout');
    });

    apnConn.on('disconnected', function() {
        console.log('Disconnected from APNS');
    });
    apnConn.on('socketError', console.error);

    return {
        init: apnConn,
        note: function (obj) {
            var note = new apn.Notification();
            note.setAlertText(obj.alert);
            note.badge = 1;
            return note;
        }
    }
};
```

Error :

```
server.apnConnection.note("test");
                 ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/server/index.js:60:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:501:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applepush.js` exports a function, not an object. The object you are looking for is returned by the exported function.

You probably should write something like:

```
server = require('./config/server/hapi.js')(config, process.env.NODE_URL);
// Note the function call.
server.apnConnection = require('./config/server/applepush.js')();
server.apnConnection.note("test");
```

Another solution is to  modify `applepush.js` so that it returns an object instead of a function. However it seems that the goal of this function is to set up a server, and you may not want this server to be set up as soon as the module is loaded.

Comment: ah, so as of now I've only returned the function which RETURNS the object I was expecting.. 

apnConnection should be setup after `server` , yes.

Comment: turns out I'll need `require(...path-to-js-file)(config)` , but other than that it worked!

Thank you!